# Issue updating from AspNetCore Identity 1.0 to 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity

When I update Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore from 1.0 to 1.1 the [Authorize] attribute fails to redirect to the login page, I just get a blank page.

Does anyone know if there have been any breaking changes that could have caused this?

I am using the default /Account/Login

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("Identity:Password:RequireDigit");
    options.Password.RequiredLength = Configuration.GetValue<int>("Identity:Password:RequiredLength");
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("Identity:Password:RequireLowercase");
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("Identity:Password:RequireNonAlphanumeric");
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("Identity:Password:RequireUppercase");

    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = Configuration.GetValue<int>("Identity:Lockout:MaxFailedAccessAttempts"); ;

    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("Identity:SignIn:RequireConfirmedEmail");

    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("Identity:User:RequireUniqueEmail");


})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I can replicate this with the boilerplate VS 2015 project.

1. New Project
2. ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)
3. 'Web Application' Template
4. 'Individual User Accounts' Authentication
5. Open website to /Manage/Index and it will redirect to /Account/Login
6. Set these to 1.1

   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0"

   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0"

   "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0"
7. Open website to /Manage/Index and it will open a blank page

I am using .NET 4.6.1, here is the updated project.json

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-MPS.IdentityServer-3b3bb17d-2d5b-4d07-a62f-0c092febc156",

  "dependencies": {
    "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation": "1.0.0-alpha3-final",
    "esendex-dotnet-sdk": "2.5.0",
    "MailKit": "1.10.1",
    //"Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    //"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0",
    //"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0",
    //"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "OpenIddict": "1.0.0-*",
    "OpenIddict.Mvc": "1.0.0-*",
    "Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Serilog.Settings.Configuration": "2.1.0",
    "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile": "2.2.0",
    "System.Reflection.Extensions": "4.0.0"
  },    

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },    

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {}
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },    

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },    

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings*.json",
      "web.config"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "wwwroot/lib/",
      "wwwroot/_references.js",
      "wwwroot/css/src",
      "wwwroot/css/bootstrap-override.css",
      "wwwroot/js/src",
      "Views/Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation.cshtml",
      "Views/Account/ExternalLoginFailure.cshtml",
      "Views/Manage/ManageLogins.cshtml",
      "Views/Manage/SetPassword.cshtml"
    ]
  },    

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "configurations": {
    "Test": {}
  }        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Update the following:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
```

to

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
```

How I figured it out: I ran via Kestrel to get the command line output window hoping to see an error.  Instead, it worked.  So I realized there must be something new in the IIS integration piece.

Comment: thanks. I've tried setting IISIntegration to 1.1 along with the others but it still fails

Comment: Really?  I just re-followed your steps with a brand new project and set the 4 packages (your 3 + my 1) to 1.1.0 and it works as expected with the login redirect.  Perhaps this is a works on my machine problem where I have something installed differently. Sadly, I'm not sure how to figure that out.

Comment: @Dave As a sanity check, I tried the same thing again on a different computer.  Same steps: new project, add the 3 version updates and it doesn't work. add the IISIntegration version update and it starts to work.  At a loss for what else you may have changed.  Did you try from a new project?

Comment: Ah, yes it works. It only seems to work if i'm targetting .NET Core though. If I target .NET Framework 4.6.1 it doesn't work

Comment: I ported over your entire project.json a few at a time (used a diff tool to be sure I got them all) and it still continued to work.  Changing IIS Integration from 1.0.0 to 1.1 and back again confirmed the same break/fixed behaviour.  Unfortunately I'm at a loss.  Last ditch effort would be to delete the project.lock.json and let it regenerate.  I've seen the lock file trip on itself and it could be due to version mismatches with your referenced projects and it getting confused with which versions is the correct one.  I couldn't duplicate your referenced projects so that could be it.